# Times as reported in FitNesse results

Tags: fitnesse

I'm testing web services in FitNesse, when I run a page of tests the test results page includes a time in ms, such as

Assertions: 18 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions (0.010 seconds)

What does the 0.010 seconds actually refer to? It may sound like a dumb question but if I count the time taken for the tests to complete and reload the results page it actually takes 10 seconds. What's the difference?

Thanks,

James.

Comment: I've understood this as the time taken to execute the actual test - as opposed to the time taken to render the output results page (which is what you're measuring with a stopwatch) - but I don't have a reference to back this up.

Comment: That's interesting. But I can run the same tests with the same results returned on a different environment where the page takes 63 seconds to return but the time reported in fitnesse is 0.020 seconds. I'm just struggling to understand the time differences.

Comment: Are you running a test that has a SuiteSetUp and SuiteTearDown?  I think there could be a bug in that situation where the page is returning the wrong time.

Comment: All tests had SuiteSetUp and SuiteTearDown. Maybe I should write some simple tests with no setup and teardown to allow me to understand what the numbers are telling me.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the time the test actually took to complete. The reason it doesn't seem to only take milliseconds is because its only counting the execution time of the test itself. The extra time delay is caused by generating the results and the communication with the server running the tests (theres a delay even if you run it locally)